# Upgrade Nifi Registry

Tags: registry, apache-nifi, upgrade, apache-nifi-registry

I have an older Nifi Registry version of 0.8.0 and I want to upgrade it to the latest 1.19.1 version. I have copied the conf from old version to new version along with the following folders.

Is there something else that needs to be done because this has not worked. On starting Nifi Registry, the logs say that the Nifi Registry UI is now available at given URLs but its in fact not reachable at all.

It works fine with version 0.8.0.

Is there a need to migrate the data somehow using a tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was resolved by trying a later version. I followed the steps with version 1.20.0 and it works fine. It seems to be a bug in 1.19.1 with certain OS or environments.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you able to upgrade to 1.19.0 . I tried the upgrade recently and I'm getting an error like flow_git directory is not present. It's cluster deployment.

Comment: I have still not been able to upgrade it yet. This is the resource I followed for the upgrade in the first place. But after restarting, Nifi registry starts up but I can the UI is not reachable.

Comment: Ok, On running the docker image locally I'm able to get UI. I'm getting an issue on deploying it in Kubernetes